# Writing file to network drive in stored proc

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a stored proc that can write a file to a network drive using BCP, by creating a temporary drive on the database server that maps to the shared drive on another server.  It is working correctly, however, I am returning an error from the last `EXEC` command, which says `There are open files and/or incomplete directory searches pending on the connection to U:.` I am guessing that it is trying to execute the delete drive command before it has finished writing the file.  If I run the statement after running the proc, it will successfully delete the drive. Here is the proc:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dn_ExportFile
    @ServerName varchar(50),
    @ServerPath varchar(500),
    @FileName varchar(100),
    @Query varchar(max),
    @UserName varchar(100),
    @Password varchar(100),
    @Drive varchar(1) = 'U'
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    DECLARE @cmd VARCHAR(8000)

    --Set up virtual drive pointing to desired path
    SET @cmd = 'NET USE ' + @Drive + ': ' + @ServerPath + ' /user:' + @ServerName + '\' + @UserName + ' ' + @Password
    PRINT @cmd
    EXEC xp_cmdshell @cmd

    --Export data using BCP to virtual drive
    SET @cmd = 'BCP "' + @Query + '" QUERYOUT "' + @Drive + ':\' + @FileName + '" -c -t -T'
    PRINT @cmd
    EXEC xp_cmdshell @cmd

    --Delete virtual drive
    SET @cmd = 'NET USE ' + @Drive + ': /delete'
    PRINT @cmd
    EXEC xp_cmdshell @cmd
END
```

Is there a way to successfully delete the temporary drive within the stored procedure?

Comment: While I would suggest consuming the results of the query from a program instead of having SQL Server write to the network drive directly, it may just be a timing issue. Have you tried adding a `WAITFOR DELAY '00:00:05';` before the last command?

Comment: yes i tried the delay and it didn't do the trick

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect it can't happen while the calling proc is still in scope. So you might try a wrapper stored procedure that does:

```
EXEC dbo.dn_ExportFile ...;

SET @cmd = 'NET USE ' + @Drive + ': /delete';
PRINT @cmd;
EXEC xp_cmdshell @cmd;
```

Otherwise I still think you're doing this in the wrong place. Have the program that calls this procedure call the command and dictate the path.

Comment: I agree that it's much easier to work with the file system from a program, but I'd like for this proc to work so I can use it within a SQL Server Agent Job.  You're right about it not working within the proc itself, because the fix you're suggesting does indeed work.  I'm wondering if there's some way to "close" a BCP file manually or something

Comment: A SQL Server Agent job can call a cmd exe or a PowerShell script just as easily as it can call a stored procedure. And I don't think it has anything to do with "closing" the BCP file, it's the process invoked by the procedure still having a hold of the shared drive. This is why it works when the procedure has gone out of scope.

Comment: Thanks for your help, and I'll start moving towards the setup you describe.  However, for now, I've found that appending "/y" to the command, it forces the disconnect by answering yes to the prompt which asks "Is it OK to continue disconnecting and force them closed? (Y/N) [N]: "  Thanks again

Comment: @WillP. ah, interesting, glad there was a more immediate solution (I never would have guessed there was some kind of a prompt to suppress - usually if the program is waiting on input it hangs the stored procedure completely).